# Creating in-article index that references heading types

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-articles

I am wondering if it is possible to add an index that references specific heading types on a LinkedIn article.

Let's say that I have an article with the following structure:

A bit about me (Heading 1)

About (Heading 2)

Projects (Heading 2)

Services (Heading 2)

And I want to create an in-article index, that allows me to reference headings 1 and 2, and, by pressing, for example, 1. About, it would take me to that specific part of the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that feature is not available at this point of time.

Just received a [message from a LinkedIn Moderator](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/10325006):

> Thank you for asking this on the forum. We do not have this feature at
>   this point of time. However, I will surely pass this message on to our
>   internal team as feedback.
>
> When many of our members ask for the same improvement, we try our best
>   to get it done. However, due to the large number of suggestions we
>   receive, we can't provide a timeline.   You can also keep up with the
>   latest product news and enhancements on our official blog
>   http://blog.linkedin.com for additional feature updates and fixes.
>   It's our way of keeping you informed on all the exciting work we're
>   doing behind the scenes.